# How to prove this combinatorial identity without using committee argument but direct manipulation?

Tags: combinatorics

$C(n,r)=C(r,r)\cdot C(n-r,0) + C(r,r-1)\cdot C(n-r,1)+\ldots+ C(r,1)\cdot C(n-r, r-1)+C(r,0)\cdot C(n-r,r)$

Using the committee argument, it is pretty straight forward:
We are dividing $n$ people into two groups $A$ and $B$ each of cardinality $r$ and $n-r$ and then selecting $r$ from these $n$ people in following way:

For $0\leq i \leq r$, We select $i$ from group $A$ in $C(r,i)$ ways  and the remaining $r-i$ from $B$ in $C(n-r,r-i)$ ways. For fixed $i$, we henceforth select $r$ people from the lot in $C(r,i)\cdot C(n-r,r-i$ ways so that $i$ come from $A$ and $r-i$ come from B(using rule of product, as both tasks are compulsory).

Since the task of selecting $r$ people from the lot so that $i$ come from $A$ and $n-i$ come from $B$ is disjoint for each $i$, the rule of sum gives the above identity.

But how do I prove this identity directly using manipulation.

Comment: This is a particular case of the Chu--Vandermonde identity aka the Vandermonde convolution. The general statement is $\dbinom{x+y}{n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{x}{k} \dbinom{y}{n-k}$ for any numbers $x$ and $y$ and any nonnegative integer $n$. There are algebraic proofs around for various tastes. See, e.g., §3.3.2 (first proof of Theorem 3.29) in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, Version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). Your question is obtained by plugging $r$, $n-r$ and $r$ for $x$, $y$ and $n$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You should consider posting an answer based on what you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case of the Chu--Vandermonde identity.

The *Chu--Vandermonde identity* (also known as *Vandermonde convolution*) states that
\begin{align}
\dbinom{x+y}{n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{x}{k} \dbinom{y}{n-k}
\label{darij1.eq.chu}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
for any numbers $x$ and $y$ (not necessarily integers) and any nonnegative integer $n$. There are algebraic proofs around for various tastes. See, e.g., §3.3.2 (first proof of Theorem 3.29) in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, Version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). This proof (an induction on $n$ using the absorption formula $\dbinom{y}{n} = \dfrac{y}{n} \dbinom{y-1}{n-1}$) has the advantage that it works uniformly for all $x$ and $y$. If you content yourself with a proof that requires $x$ to be a nonnegative integer, then there are simpler ones around, such as the First proof of Theorem 1.3.37 in [my *Enumerative Combinatorics: class notes*](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19fco/n/n.pdf) (an induction on $x$ essentially, although I frame it as an induction on an auxiliary variable).

To recover your formula, apply \eqref{darij1.eq.chu} to $r$, $n-r$ and $r$ instead of $x$, $y$ and $n$. You obtain
\begin{align}
\dbinom{r+\left(n-r\right)}{r} &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^r \dbinom{r}{k} \dbinom{n-r}{r-k} \\
&= \dbinom{r}{r} \dbinom{n-r}{0} + \dbinom{r}{r-1} \dbinom{n-r}{1} + \cdots + \dbinom{r}{1} \dbinom{n-r}{r-1} + \dbinom{r}{0} \dbinom{n-r}{r}
\end{align}
(here, we have written out the sum from last to first addend). In view of $r + \left(n-r\right) = n$, this rewrites as
\begin{align}
\dbinom{n}{r} &= \dbinom{r}{r} \dbinom{n-r}{0} + \dbinom{r}{r-1} \dbinom{n-r}{1} + \cdots + \dbinom{r}{1} \dbinom{n-r}{r-1} + \dbinom{r}{0} \dbinom{n-r}{r} .
\end{align}
This is precisely your formula.